# Find a substring in a large string which includes potential characters with Regex

Tags: regex, string

I have a long string of characters, and within this string, some positions could have different potential values displayed between brackets.

For example in this string, a position can sometime have 2 or more value, and are enclosed between brackets. (**This is my test string!**) :

```
NVSA(LR)TFRVLRA(LK)TISVIPGLKTI(VG)ALIQSVKKLS(DV)MIL(TVFC)LSVFALI...
```

Now I would like to search some specific substrings in this big string above by taking into account the potential values displayed.

***EXAMPLE :***

My **test string** begin like that : `NVSA(LR)TFRVLRA(LK)TISV`.

I want to know if `NVSARTF` and `LRAKTI` can be found in this string (should return a match).
Likewise `NVSAQTF`should not be found.

How to write the regex ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you have possible values in round brackets `( )` you just have to use square brackets `[ ]` and you're done with your Regex...

Regex `NVSA[LR]TF` will find `NVSALTF` or `NVSARTF`

**edit:**
concluding your comment below you mean something along this way...
This Regex will find `NVSALTF`

```
(?:N|\([^)]*N[^)]*\))(?:V|\([^)]*V[^)]*\))(?:S|\([^)]*S[^)]*\))(?:A|\([^)]*A[^)]*\))(?:L|\([^)]*L[^)]*\))(?:T|\([^)]*T[^)]*\))(?:F|\([^)]*F[^)]*\))
```

You could replace every character of your String you search for (e.g. `X`) with that Regex pattern `(?:X|\([^)]*X[^)]*\))` and concatenate a huge Regex...

test Regexp [here](http://rubular.com/r/cmNpQrJKxV)

Maybe Regex is not the right solution for this type of problem...

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear, I know that, but in my case ```NVSA(LR)TFRVLR``` or ```NVSA[LR]TFRVLR``` is the test string, not the regex. I need a regex that will look this big string with brackets and find a match for ```NVSALTF ```.

Comment: the question is indeed still quite confusing

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think we're almost there but not quite yet. In the example, if i change your string to:

```
(?:L|\([^)]*L[^)]*\))(?:R|\([^)]*R[^)]*\))
```

and still given

```
NVSA(LR)TFRVLRA(LK)TISVIPGLKTI(VG)ALIQSVKKLS(DV)MIL(TVFC)LSVFALI
```

it will catch both the `LR` in `VLRA` and in `(LR)`,
but the second means and must be either a `L` or a `R`, not a `LR` sequence.

Comment: adding some regexp lookahead would help in this case but result in an almost unreadable regexp:

`(?:L(?![^(]*\))|\([^)]*L[^)]*\))(?:R(?![^(]*\))|\([^)]*R[^)]*\))`